# Storing containers in a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, std

The last line here:

```
typedef boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>> C; 

class A: public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(const std::vector<int>& value) const
    {
    }

    void operator()(const std::vector<float>& value) const
    {
    }
};

C container(std::vector<float>());
boost::apply_visitor(A(), container );
```

Is giving me the error:

```
c:\boost_1_49_0\boost\variant\detail\apply_visitor_unary.hpp(60): error C2228: left of '.apply_visitor' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'boost::variant<T0_,T1> (__cdecl &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=std::vector<int>,
1>              T1=std::vector<float>
1>          ]
1>          c:\visual studio 2010\projects\db\xxx\main.cpp(255) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::apply_visitor<A,C(std::vector<_Ty> (__cdecl *)(void))>(Visitor &,Visitable (__cdecl &))' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=float,
1>              Visitor=A,
1>              Visitable=C (std::vector<float> (__cdecl *)(void))
```

What is the problem here? Is it sensible in you opinion to have a container type C which such a definition?

I am using the following type throughout my code:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, ...> Type;
```

Do you think it would be wiser to use this container definition instead:

```
typedef std::vector<Type> C; // mixed container
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that this

```
C container(std::vector<float>());
```

is a function declaration (that’s the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) (a function `container` which takes a function returning `std::vector<float>` as its sole argument, and returns `C`). Easy fix: extra parentheses:

```
C container((std::vector<float>()));
```

The fact that you’re using containers in the `variant` is irrelevant to the problem. The same would have happened with `boost::variant<int, float>`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should use the first typedef ... C; definition or the second?

Comment: @Baz Whichever makes sense for you, the two are not interchangeable.

Comment: I prefer the first since it defines a container containing values of the same type. The second definition I would use if I wished to have values of different types within the container, which I actually don't.